# Insert element before other elements in the same div using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add divs by using JavaScript in the parentDiv. I have already created some divs in my index.html file. I want that the div I will create will be added before other divs I created in html in the same parentDiv. I don't want to remove other divs. I tried using appendChild but that adds in the end.
Hope it makes sense.

```
function displayBox(data) {
  let html = "";

  data.forEach((box) => {
  const box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
    html = `
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="${box.link}"
        class="image fit"
        ><img
            src="${box.img}"
            alt="${box.name}"
        /></a>
        <div class="inner">
        <h3>${box.name} (${box.country})</h3>
        <a
            target="_blank"
            href="${box.link}"
            class="button open-link fit"
            >Visit</a
        >
        </div>
      `;
    box.innerHTML = html;
    thumbnails.appendChild(box);
  });
  
}
```

thumbnails is my parentDiv where I want to add divs named box

Comment: Mistakes in your code should be fixed by an [edit] of the question. Expecting others to ignore them in an environment where you are asking for troubleshooting help doesn't make any sense

Comment: Please tell me how to add a div created by using javascript before other divs created in html file in the same parent Div.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved the problem in this way. Thanks epascarello

```
function displayBox(data) {
  data = data.reverse();
  let html = "";

  data.forEach((box) => {
  const box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
    html = `
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="${box.link}"
        class="image fit"
        ><img
            src="${box.img}"
            alt="${box.name}"
        /></a>
        <div class="inner">
        <h3>${box.name} (${box.country})</h3>
        <a
            target="_blank"
            href="${box.link}"
            class="button open-link fit"
            >Visit</a
        >
        </div>
      `;
    box.innerHTML = html;
    thumbnails.prepend(box);
  });
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add elements to the front you can use prepend.

```js
var data = [1,2,3];

var out = document.querySelector("#out");
data.forEach(function (x) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = x;
  out.prepend(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="out">

  <div>Orginal</div>
</div>
```

If you want to not be in revser order, you can either loop in reverse or change the code to use before() with the first element in the parent.

```js
var data = [1,2,3];

var out = document.querySelector("#out");
const first = out.children[0];
data.forEach(function (x) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = x;
  first.before(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="out">

  <div>Orginal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used prepend with reverse method and it solved my problem.